PM2 Restart issue
pm2 restart 0 --cron-restart="0 0 * * *"

Will this restart instance 0 everyday at midnight? Or is there a better way to do this?
I need to restart instance 0 once a day.
Also since I ran the above command, how
can I disable it when I don't need it restarting anymore?

Why do you need to restart every day at midnight?
